# React FormControl onChange not being triggered

Tags: reactjs, form-control

I am trying to get a simple form working in React but I can't seem to get it working. I am also using `react-bootstrap` for my GUI components.
I have a component called `Inventory` that holds the form:

```
class Inventory extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            'upc' : ''
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) { this.setState({'upc' : event.target.value }); }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <h1>Inventory Page</h1>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group className="mb3" controlId="invUpcForm">
                                <Form.Label>UPC</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="123456789012" />
                                <Form.Text value={this.state.upc} onChange={this.handleChange} className="text-muted">
                                    Ensure the field is focused, and scan the barcode.
                                </Form.Text>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

However, whenever I enter any text into the Input field, `handleChange` never gets called despite the value of the field changing. If I submit the field, checking the value of `upc` in state shows it is empty `''`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is your `onChange={this.chng}`?

Comment: A remnant from testing different fixes. Issue remains with the proper `this.handleChange` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this example](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/form-text/#form-text) from the [react-bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/forms/form-control/), you should be attaching your `value` and `onChange` props to the `<Form.Control />` component, not `<Form.Text />`. Form text is for help text, while the form controls handle the actual input elements.

Comment: Well I feel a little bit silly! That works perfectly thank you. I guess the `FormControl.Text` in my head lead me to think of it as the input field when it's just simple text under the input.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta change like this.

```
 render() {
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <h1>Inventory Page</h1>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Group className="mb3" controlId="invUpcForm">
                                <Form.Label>UPC</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                   type="text" 
                                   placeholder="123456789012"
                                   value={this.state.upc} 
                                   onChange={this.handleChange} 
                                />
                                <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                                    Ensure the field is focused, and scan the barcode.
                                </Form.Text>
                            </Form.Group>
                            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

It is because Form.Control is a real input component, and Form.Text component is just a simple div/span to render text. You can check it by inspecting element in chrome browser.